# Error 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlsplit'

Tags: python, pip, python-sphinx, six, urlsplit

Error Running Sphinx with Six. When I run Make HTML in project docs, I get the error

```
 Running Sphinx v1.4.1 making output directory...
1.4.1
loading pickled environment... not yet created

Exception occurred:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/intersphinx.py", line 148, in _strip_basic_auth
    url_parts = parse.urlsplit(url)
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlsplit'
```

The six package says its at 1.4.1 but when run pip list

```
alabaster (0.7.7)
awscli (1.10.23)
awsebcli (3.7.6)
Babel (2.3.3)
blessed (1.9.5)
botocore (1.4.14)
cement (2.8.2)
colorama (0.3.3)
CommonMark (0.5.4)
docker-py (1.7.2)
dockerpty (0.4.1)
docopt (0.6.2)
docutils (0.12)
futures (3.0.5)
google-api-python-client (1.5.1)
httplib2 (0.9.2)
imagesize (0.7.0)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jmespath (0.9.0)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
oauth2client (2.2.0)
pathspec (0.3.4)
pip (8.1.2)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.8)
Pygments (2.1.3)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
pytz (2016.4)
PyYAML (3.11)
recommonmark (0.4.0)
requests (2.9.1)
rsa (3.3)
s3transfer (0.0.1)
semantic-version (2.5.0)
setuptools (19.4)
simplejson (3.8.2)
six (1.5.0)
snowballstemmer (1.2.1)
Sphinx (1.4.1)
sphinx-rtd-theme (0.1.9)
texttable (0.8.4)
uritemplate (0.6)
virtualenv (15.0.2)
wcwidth (0.1.6)
websocket-client (0.37.0)
wheel (0.26.0)
```

Its at 1.5.0

Can anyone see the problem here?
Thanks a mill.
Vin

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue. I needed to update Sphinx to 1.4.4